# Polymer change app color

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am working on an app using polymer in that I have a file called shared styles which looks like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<!-- shared styles for all views -->
<dom-module id="shared-styles">
<template>
<style>

 :host {
    --app-primary-color: red;
    --app-secondary-color: black;
    display: block;
    }

  .card {
    margin: 24px;
    padding: 16px;
    color: #757575;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }

  h1 {
    margin: 16px 0;
    color: #212121;
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  img{
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
  }
</style>
```

Here what I am doing is I am using the same color  **--app-primary-color:red** all over my app what I want to do is I want to change this color value from some page so that the changed color reflects all over the app.

```
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">
<dom-module id="my-view">
<template>
<style include="shared-styles">

footer {
    position: fixed;
    background: var(--app-primary-color);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
</style>
<paper-button noink  on-tap="_changeColor" >change color</paper-button>

<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'my-view7',
      _changeColor: function(){
      var myElement = document.querySelector("#host");
      myElement.style.--app-primary-color = "blue";
    }
    });
```

How can I make it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible from shared-style.

However, custom CSS properties defined in a parent element are accessible by its children. Since you have a `my-view` element, you probably also have a parent `my-app` element. You can move `--app-primary-color` and `--app-secondary-color` in `my-app`'s `:host` selector.

Comment: thank you @agaudin i moved --app-primary-color to my-app and created a binding in my-view and used observer in my-app to update the color of --app-primary-color on color change done in my-view..